# Cant push autocomplete selected value to global array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Im working on a project in which I have autocomplete with users list.

when I try to push autocomplete selected value to global array I get an empty list when I do console.info(usernames) outside autocomplete function.

```
var usernames=[];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){

     $( "#users" ).autocomplete({

   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "getUserFromDb.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event,ui){
    usernames.push(ui.item.value);
    }
});
console.info(usernames);
  });

    });
```

soruce of autocomplete is returning correct list and select works as well, because if I do console.info(usernames) inside autocomplete select: the list will update when im selecting different values.

Comment: Please just dump your complete code, Post only relevant portion.

Comment: You are better of using `var usernames=[];` instead if `var usernames=new Array;`

Comment: @LShetty this wont solve my problem

Comment: @Ollikas neither did I say so! And, again, do not have multiple `ready` handlers. `$(document).ready(function(){` == `$(function(){` => [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfpohjne/1/)

Comment: I think my code has more duplicates and unnecessary code, but i would like to get an answer to my question...

Comment: Have you tried printing usernames from a javascript console? I'm guessing that console.info is only being called once, and before anything is pushed to username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you needed an "answer", here we go. First off, your `console.info` has run as soon as the DOM is ready and obviously empty as the user names are pushed in later on, when you select options from autocomplete. Secondly, you are not re-logging `usernames` as and when it's populated. So, you have 2 options.

1) log `usernames` within the select function, such as:

```
select: function(event,ui) {
    usernames.push(ui.item.value);
    console.info(usernames);
}
```

2) Have a function that would do the job for you, such as:

```
select: function(event,ui) {
    usernames.push(ui.item.value);
    showMeUserNames();
}

function showMeUserNames() {
    console.info(usernames);
}
```

So, your code may become:

```
var usernames=[];

$(function(){
    $( "#users" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getUserFromDb.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event,ui) {
            usernames.push(ui.item.value);
            console.info(usernames);
            // OR
            // showMeUserNames();
        }
    });
});

function showMeUserNames() {
    console.info(usernames);
}
```

Comment: so in other words i have my list populated , but I was displaying it wrong.

Comment: Yes.  You were displaying it before it was even populated!